# Getting difference between two dates in number of days?

Tags: c, date, time

I am not getting the correct days while comparing two days. Here, I am getting 699 days instead of 730 days for `dd=14,mm=8,yy=2014`

```
time_t t1, t2;
struct tm my_target_date;

 my_target_date.tm_sec = 0;
 my_target_date.tm_min = 0;
 my_target_date.tm_hour = 0;
 my_target_date.tm_mday = 14;
 my_target_date.tm_mon = 8;
 my_target_date.tm_year = 112; /* Date today */
 t1 = mktime (&my_target_date);
 t2 = time (NULL);
 sprintf (sbuff2,"Number of days since target date : %ld\n", (t2 - t1) / 86400);
```

Comment: In addition to being a month off, before calling `mktime(&my_target_date);`, set `my_target_date.tm_isdst`.  Use `my_target_date.tm_isdst  = -1;` if unsure of daylight savings time setting.   The other 2 fields `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` do not need to be set.

Answer (score 6):

In `struct tm`,

```
int tm_mday; // day of the month — [1, 31]
int tm_mon; // months since January — [0, 11]
```

`tm_mday` starts from `1`, but `tm_mon` starts from `0`. Thus `my_target_date.tm_mon = 8;` is actually September, you are off by one month.

Answer (score 0):

`struct tm` structure is-

```
struct tm {
           int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
           int tm_min;         /* minutes */
           int tm_hour;        /* hours */
           int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
           int tm_mon;         /* month */
           int tm_year;        /* year */
           int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
           int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
           int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
       };
```

The members of the tm structure are:

```
   tm_sec    The  number of seconds after the minute, normally in the range 0 to 59, but can be up
             to 60 to allow for leap seconds.

   tm_min    The number of minutes after the hour, in the range 0 to 59.

   tm_hour   The number of hours past midnight, in the range 0 to 23.

   tm_mday   The day of the month, in the range 1 to 31.

   tm_mon    The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.

   tm_year   The number of years since 1900.

   tm_wday   The number of days since Sunday, in the range 0 to 6.

   tm_yday   The number of days since January 1, in the range 0 to 365.

   tm_isdst  A flag that indicates  whether  daylight  saving  time  is  in  effect  at  the  time
             described.  The value is positive if daylight saving time is in effect, zero if it is
             not, and negative if the information is not available.
```

If you take input as `dd=14,mm=8,yy=2014`, it indicates that September 14th 2014, because in `tm_mon` month starting from `0`. so it will calculate the no of days from `September 14th 2014`. so you are missing 31 days in between.

Make your input as `dd=14,mm=7,yy=2014`.